# Cannot compile Gsoap 2.8.123 using WS-Security on c++

Tags: c++, soap

I want use messages in http://www.onvif.org/ver10/advancedsecurity/wsdl/advancedsecurity.wsdl

From cmd prompt I run Wsdl2h and soapcpp2, they generate the cpp files that I included in my project.
Then I compile my project following those instruction:
https://www.genivia.com/examples/onvif/index.html  (Using WS-Security)

The project is not built I've 657 errors in wsseapi.cpp:

it doesn't recognize wsse__Security in struct soap inside soap file wsseapi.cpp

Has someone faced this problem?

I tried to disable SSL security and the project is built with no error, but I need enable SSL using WS-Security.
I'm expecting that there are some configuration in soap to manage this situation.